# Access violating writing location (visual studio 2008) Code based on pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, access-violation, unions

The main problem is after sem->i = a; is used when yylex is called and c isalpha
 sem->s[i] = c; doesn't work because sem->s[i] has an issue with the adress it points to.

more details:
So what i want to do is to open a txt and read what it is inside until the end of file.
If it's an alfanumeric (example: hello ,example2 hello45a) at the function yylex i put each of the characters into an array(sem->s[i]) until i find end of file or something not alfanumeric.
If it's a digit (example: 5234254 example2: 5) at the function yylex i put each of the characters into the array arithmoi[]. and after with attoi i put the number into the sem->i.
If i delete the else if(isdigit(c)) part at yylex it works(if every word in the txt doesn't start with a digit) .
Anyway the thing is that it works great when it finds only words that starts with characters. Then if it finds number(it uses the elseif(isdigit(c) part) it still works...until it finds a words starting with a character. when that happens there is an access violating writing location and the problem seems to be where i have an arrow. if you can help me i would be really thankfull.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union SEMANTIC_INFO
{
    int i;
    char *s;
};


int yylex(FILE *fpointer, SEMANTIC_INFO *sem)
{
    char c;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    c = fgetc (fpointer);
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        if(isalpha(c))
        {
           do
           {
               sem->s[i] = c;//the problem is here... <-------------------
                       c = fgetc(fpointer); 
               i++;
           }while(isalnum(c));
        return 1;
        }
        else if(isdigit(c))
        {
            char arithmoi[20];
            do
            {
                arithmoi[j] = c;
                j++;
                c = fgetc(fpointer);
            }while(isdigit(c));
            sem->i = atoi(arithmoi); //when this is used the sem->s[i] in if(isalpha) doesn't work
            return 2;
        }
    }
    cout << "end of file" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i,k;
    char c[20];
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    for(i=0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        c[i] = ' ';
    }
    SEMANTIC_INFO sematic;
    SEMANTIC_INFO *sema = &sematic;
    sematic.s = c;
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("piri.txt", "r");
    do
    {
       k = yylex( pFile, sema);
       if(k == 1)
       {
           counter1++;
           cout << "it's type is alfanumeric and it's: ";
          for(i=0; i<20; i++)
          {
              cout << sematic.s[i] << " " ;
          }
          cout <<endl;
          for(i=0; i < 20; i++)
          {
              c[i] = ' ';
          }
       }
       else if(k==2)
       {
           counter2++;
           cout << "it's type is digit and it's: "<< sematic.i << endl;

       }
    }while(k != 0);
    cout<<"the alfanumeric are : " << counter1 << endl;
    cout<<"the digits are: " << counter2 << endl;
    fclose (pFile);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually it won't work even on the sample data you provided: `hello ,example2 hello45a`. The loop `while(c != EOF)` won't end if `c` is a punctuation mark, a comma in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This line in `main` is creating an **uninitialized** `SEMANTIC_INFO`

```
SEMANTIC_INFO sematic;
```

The value of integer `sematic.i` is unknown.

The value of pointer `sematic.s` is unknown.

You then try to write to `sematic.s[0]`.  You're hoping that `sematic.s` points to writable memory, large enough to hold the contents of that file, but you haven't made it point to anything.

Comment: in main sematic.s points to array c[20]. sema points to semantic. Then i call yylex passing sema and there i give vallues to sema->i and sema->s[i] .try to run it but creat a txt in the same folder and write something(for example i have a white horse) and then try to write (i have 1 white horse) and see what happens